# Framework for a perfect touch ready, iPad compatible and content swipe-ready site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, sliding

I am trying to find some JS framework which can help me bring touch and swipe functionality in a site for both iPad and Web. Since the site would preferably be opened with an iPad, I want to integrate the touch and swipe functionality effectively.

Searching around, I found [dragend](http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/), which is a perfect JS for doing all aforementioned. But the problem is, that it doesn't let me click the links on a page within iPad. On the Web, in any browser, links would be clicked (normally) and the content would be slided as needed, but when it is opened in an iPad, link clicking doesn't work, while sliding works fine.

As a test, you can visit http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/, and open it in Web and iPad. The links on it wouldn't work on iPad.

Could you guys help me find a good JS framework for my requirements?

I know this is not a programming question and I apologize if it doesn't get to the mark of your perceived quality-bar.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [hammerjs](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) or [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)?  I have used both before and found them to be quite good.